# Find all direct and indirect end child

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have table like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Child ID`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`Flag`**</kbd> 
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C01`</kbd>       <kbd>`Y`</kbd>    
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C02`</kbd>       <kbd>`Y`</kbd>    
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`AC01`</kbd>      <kbd>`N`</kbd>    
<kbd>`AC01`</kbd>      <kbd>`C03`</kbd>       <kbd>`Y`</kbd>    
<kbd>`AC01`</kbd>      <kbd>`AC02`</kbd>      <kbd>`N`</kbd>    
<kbd>`AC02`</kbd>      <kbd>`C04`</kbd>       <kbd>`Y`</kbd>

So here A01 is **direct parent** of C01,C02 and AC01. AC01 is **direct parent** of C03 and AC02 and AC02 is **direct parent** of C04.C01,C02,C03 and C04 don't have any child. So they are like **end children**. that's why their **flag is 'Y'**. But AC01 and AC02 are not like **pure end child**.And also C03 and C04 are **indirect children** of A01.

> **I want to list down all direct and indirect end children(Flag ='Y') of a particular ID.Something like below:**

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Child ID`**</kbd>  
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C01`</kbd>       
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C02`</kbd>       
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C03`</kbd>       
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`C04`</kbd>

The database I am using **Oracle 11G**

I have tried **recursive WITH** clause.

```
WITH  child (id,child_id) AS (
    SELECT  id,
            child_id,
            0 AS level
    FROM my_table
 
    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT  e.id, 
            e.child_id,
            level + 1
    FROM my_table e 
JOIN child s 
ON e.id = s.child_id
)
 
SELECT 
    m.id,
    s.child_id
FROM child s 
JOIN my_table m 
ON s.id = m.child_id;
```

But I am not getting desired output.

Comment: Recursive Subquery Factoring was intoduced in Oracle 11g Release 2 (that you should use anyway).

Comment: Sorry I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: Clear otherwise you'll get an `ORA-` exception. Check my answer.

Comment: 11g is a marketing name used by Oracle. It doesn't give enough information; there were two major releases, 11.1 and 11.2. Recursive subquery factoring was introduced in 11.2, so it wasn't available in 11.1. So, to say "I use 11g" is completely useless. Clearly, since the recursive `with` clause worked for you, you are using 11.2. The even better info you can share is the exact version, such as 11.2.0.4.0; to find out your version, run `select * from v$version` and see what it reports back to you.

Comment: Yes actually I am using Oracle 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursive `with` clause for this problem. It can be done, but recognizing "end" children is not trivial.

Instead, an old-fashioned `connect by` query (hierarchical query) can do quick work of this. Note that in my query (and output) I didn't include the `ID` column - you can include it if you like, but it gives you absolutely no information; it simply copies the input (`'A01'`) down the column. That is something you would know before running the query - actually, before even writing the query!

The key is the `where` clause; in a hierarchy, "end" children are known as **leaves**, and `connect_by_isleaf` returns 1 for leaves, 0 otherwise.

```
select  child_id
from    my_table
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1
start   with id = 'A01'
connect by id = prior child_id
;
```

If you insist on a solution using the recursive `with` clause, here is one way. Note the `search` clause at the end - it is key to the correct definition of the `is_leaf` column in the next subquery. One advantage of this approach is that it mimics Oracle proprietary hierarchical queries (`connect by`) using SQL standard features (recursive `with` clause).

```
with
  r (child_id, lvl) as (
    select  child_id, 1
      from  my_table
      where id = 'A01'
    union all
    select  t.child_id, r.lvl + 1
      from  my_table t join r on t.id = r.child_id
  )
  search depth first by child_id set ord
, prep (child_id, is_leaf) as (
    select child_id,
           case when lead(lvl) over (order by ord) > lvl then 0 else 1 end
    from   r
  )
select child_id
from   prep
where  is_leaf = 1
;
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, first recapitulate your data model, you typically want to have a table with an `ID` as a *primary key*, an additional column pointing to the `parent_id`.

That's enough, which `ID` is *leaf* (what you call an *end child*) is not necessary to store as you can query it.

With your data you'll get something like this

```
create table tab as
select  'A01' id, null parent_id from dual union all
select  'C01' id, 'A01' parent_id from dual union all
select  'C02' id, 'A01' parent_id from dual union all
select  'AC01' id, 'A01' parent_id from dual union all
select  'C03' id, 'AC01' parent_id from dual union all
select  'AC02' id, 'AC01' parent_id from dual union all
select  'C04' id, 'AC02' parent_id from dual ;

ID   PARENT_ID
---- ---------
A01      
C01  A01 
C02  A01 
AC01 A01 
C03  AC01
AC02 AC01
C04  AC02
```

Now the *recursive query* to get all `ID` direct or indirect dependent from a node say `A01`

```
WITH  rec (root_id, id, lvl) AS (
    SELECT  id as root_id,
            id,
            0 AS lvl
    FROM tab where id = 'A01'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  rec.root_id root_id, 
            tab.id,
            lvl + 1
    FROM tab 
    JOIN rec
    ON tab.parent_id  = rec.id
)
 
SELECT 
    rec.root_id,
    rec.id,
    rec.lvl
FROM rec 

ROOT ID          LVL
---- ---- ----------
A01  A01           0
A01  C01           1
A01  C02           1
A01  AC01          1
A01  C03           2
A01  AC02          2
A01  C04           3
```

Note that in the anchor part of the recursive query you must constraint the node you want to start with (which you are not doing).

Comment: The OP wants to include only the **end** children (the leaves) in the output. That can be done with recursive `with` clause, but it's not trivial. In any case, your solution doesn't show how to recognize leaves from non-leaves.